# how to echo exploded array line

Tags: php, arrays, filter-var

Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Numbers</title></head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="get">
<b>Numbers</b>
<br>
<textarea rows="12" cols="25" name="result" value="result"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$result=$_GET["result"];
if (empty($_GET['result']))
{
echo '<p><font size="3" color="red">Field is Empty*</font></p>';
}
elseif (isset($_GET['result']))
{
$result=(explode("\n", $result));
}
{
echo count ($result);
echo "<br />";
echo array_sum($result);
}
?>
```

Ok so I figured out how to get most of my assignment's tasks and the last 1 that I am stuck with is using similar codes such as filter_var to print out non-numerical values that are submitted. Ex. a b c * & ! @

PRINTING any invalid inputs that aren't numbers. Ex. Letters, symbols.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about `var_dump( explode("\n", $result) );`

Comment: yeah i'll try that out

Comment: What is count($result) when $result is a string?

Comment: Can you share your solution with us if you have time?

Comment: its basically the same thing as yours Aycan. $result=(explode("\n", $result));

Comment: This code is incomplete. Where is the function `filter_var()`? When are you calling `array_average()`? You'll be able to debug your code better if you indent your code with spaces or tabs. Also, there's an issue with the following lines: 
`<?php
if(!filter_var($result,FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,$options))
$no_number[]=$result;
{
` -- The `$no_number` assignment should be inside of `{}`

Comment: @hargobind filter_var is a native php function

Comment: I see. It wasn't showing up in my old offline copy of the PHP manual.

Comment: @user2896254 Deleted my answer since you changed your original question and added completely different requirements. Still a mistery on why you didn't specify them from the beginning

Comment: I didnt know how to get the exploded code correctly until you suggested you code. I'm still stuck with the even and odd as well as the invalid number input however.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code on your $result array & get the desired results:

```
$oddArray = array();
$evenArray = array();
$skippedArray = array();

    foreach($result as $value)
   {
        if(is_numeric($value))
        {
           if($value%2 == 0)
           {
               $evenArray[] = $value;
           }
           else
           {
               $oddArray[] = $value; 
           }     
        }
        else
        {
            $skippedArray[] = $value;
        }   
} 

echo "Sum of odd values entered: ".array_sum($oddArray);
echo "Sum of even values entered: ".array_sum($evenArray);
echo "Skipped invalid values entered: ";
print_r($skippedArray);
```

I hope above will help you.

Comment: Yeah thanks! it did! :) the invalid values echo out 0s however, it doesnt print the invalid values that was submitted.